# How to make my SWIG extension module work with Pickle?

Tags: python, swig, pickle

I have an extension module for Python that uses SWIG as a wrapper and I try to serialize it with Pickle and I fail =)

1. If anyone has a source of SWIG extension that can be pickled, would love to see it!
2. It seems like I should implement [`__reduce_ex__`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#pickling-and-unpickling-extension-types) method in my C++ code. Does anyone have example of `__reduce_ex__`? [There is similar Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996010/pickling-a-python-extension-type-defined-as-a-c-struct-having-pyobject-members) but it omits `manager_constructor` specification and implementation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Seems like I found simlple solution that works for me:

So let's say we have class `C` that was generated with SWIG, then we wrap it with

```
class PickalableC(C, PickalableSWIG):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args = args
        C.__init__(self)
```

where `PickalableSWIG` is

```
class PickalableSWIG:

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.__init__(*state['args'])

    def __getstate__(self):
        return {'args': self.args}
```

Then

```
pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(C()))
```

fails, but

```
pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(PickalableC()))
```

succeeds =)

Comment: In case one is interested in parallel evaluation with mpi4py, I needed to additionally implement the solution suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816958/cant-pickle-type-instancemethod-when-using-pythons-multiprocessing-pool-ma) to get it to work with instance methods of the (wrapped) class

Comment: @FredSchoen: the `dill` serializer can be used with `mpi4py`.  Just set the serializer to `dill` instead of `pickle`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21779541/mpi4py-replace-built-in-serialization

Comment: HI. I try to do this and get this error on class definition:
  class PickalableBuStress(BuStress, PickalableSWIG):
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
Can you help?

Comment: I cannot use this wrapper class in multiprocessing Manager to share it between processes.

Answer (score 6):

Here are a few additional methods.  None is of as general applicability as the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9325185/834250) is, but if your class meets some (simple) requirements then you can make pickling easier on your users by making the instances themselves (not wrapped versions) picklable.  These techniques are all used by the [LSST afw package](https://dev.lsstcorp.org/cgit/LSST/DMS/afw.git/).

Note that when unpickling using the `__getstate__`/`__setstate__` pair, the `__init__` method will **not** be called, which means that unless you're careful, you'll have an object that you can't do anything with (if you keep getting `NotImplementedError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function`, this is a possibility).  This drives us to use `__reduce__` (or you could call `__init__` from `__setstate__`).

If you're SWIG-ing class `Foo` that takes constructor arguments that you have access to from the instance (e.g., via accessors), add the following to your interface (`.i`) file:

```
%extend Foo {
%pythoncode {
    def __reduce__(self):
        # Requires matching constructor: __init__(foo, bar)
        args = self.getFoo(), self.getBar()
        return self.__class__, args
}
}
```

If you can create your object with a default constructor and then manipulate it to regain its former state, use something like this:

```
%extend Foo {
%pythoncode {
    def __getstate__(self):
        args = self.getFoo(), self.getBar()
        return args
    def __setstate__(self, state):
        # Requires empty constructor: __init__()
        self.__init__()
        foo, bar = state
        self.setFoo(foo)
        self.setBar(bar)
}
}
```

Alternatively, if your class can do a serialisation of binary data to/from memory (e.g., some in-memory representation of your own on-disk format):

```
%include "cdata.i"

%extend Foo {
%pythoncode {
    def __reduce__(self):
        s = Serializer()
        self.serialize(s)
        size = s.getLength()
        data = cdata(s.getData(), size)
        return unreduceFoo, (data, size)
}
}

%pythoncode {
def unreduceFoo(data, size):
    s = Serializer(size)
    memmove(s.getData(), data)
    return Foo(s)
}
```

Finally, if you're using `boost::serialization`, use this snippet by [Sogo Mineo](http://db.ipmu.jp/member/personal/1409en.html):

```
%{
    #include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
    #include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
    #include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
    #include <sstream>
%}
%include "std_string.i"

%define %boost_picklable(cls...)
    %extend cls {
        std::string __getstate__()
        {
            std::stringstream ss;
            boost::archive::binary_oarchive ar(ss);
            ar << *($self);
            return ss.str();
        }

        void __setstate_internal(std::string const& sState)
        {
            std::stringstream ss(sState);
            boost::archive::binary_iarchive ar(ss);
            ar >> *($self);
        }

        %pythoncode %{
            def __setstate__(self, sState):
                self.__init__()
                self.__setstate_internal(sState)
        %}
    }
%enddef

%boost_picklable(Foo)
```

Comment: The LSST afw package has since switched to pybind11, which I recommend over SWIG these days.

Answer (score 2):

I had to make a minor change to the accepted answer to make it work for my case. Since the initialization function of my class has some input arguments, I had to add an extra argument `*arg` to the `C.__init(self)` function, like so:

```
    class PickalableC(C, PickalableSWIG):
        def __init__(self, *args):
            self.args = args
            C.__init__(self, *args)
```

Maybe this is helpful for someone. I hope it is not too trivial.

I posted it as an answer since I cannot comment and learned it is not something you edit a post for.