# mpi4py: Replace built-in serialization

Tags: serialization, pickle, mpi4py, dill

I'd like to replace MPI4PY's built-in `Pickle`-serialization with dill. According to the [doc](http://mpi4py.scipy.org/docs/apiref/mpi4py.MPI._p_Pickle-class.html) the class _p_Pickle should have 2 attributes called `dumps` and `loads`. However, python says there are no such attributes when i try the following

```
from mpi4py Import MPI
MPI._p_Pickle.dumps
```

-> AttributeError: type object 'mpi4py.MPI._p_Pickle' has no attribute 'dumps'

Where have `dumps` and `loads` gone?

Comment: maybe I'm using an older Version? how 2 check mpi4py version? When I try "MPI.VERSION" it says 2...  MPI.Get_Version gives (2,1) which corresponds to (Version,Subversion). Im quite confused since the latest Version is 1.3. What the...

Comment: Maybe `MPI.Version` tells you the version of the underlining MPI implementation. Are you working with MPICH (newest version :3.0) ? or openmpi (1.7) ? or ... What is the output of `mpicc -show` ?

Answer (score 4):

In v2.0 you can change it via

```
MPI.pickle.dumps = dill.dumps
MPI.pickle.loads = dill.loads
```

It seems that the documentation is still from 2012.

**Update**
For v3.0 see [here](https://bitbucket.org/mpi4py/mpi4py/issues/82/pickling-no-longer-customizable), i.e.:

```
MPI.pickle.__init__(dill.dumps, dill.loads)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using an older version.  Use `1.3.1` not `1.2.x`.  Check the version number with `mpi4py.__version__`.  If you are using `1.3.1` or newer, you can overload `dumps` and `loads` with serialization from `dill`, or `cloudpickle`, or a some other custom serializer.

```
>>> import mpi4py
>>> mpi4py.__version__
'1.3.1'
```