# Python: (Pathos) Multiprocessing vs. class methods

Tags: python, pickle, python-multiprocessing, pathos

I am trying to parallelize a code using class methods via multiprocessing. The basic structure is the following:

```
# from multiprocessing import Pool
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool

class myclass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        #some code
    def mymethod(self):
        #more code
        return another_instance_of_myclass



def myfunc(myinstance,args):
    #some code   
    test=myinstance.mymethod()
    #more code
    return myresult #not an instance,just a number

p=Pool()

result = p.map(myfunc,listwithdata)
```

After this had failed with the normal multiprocessing, I became aware of the issues with Pickle and Multiprocessing, so I tried to solve it with multiprocessing.pathos. However, I am still getting

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'SwigPyObject'>: it's not found as__builtin__.SwigPyObjec
```

together with lots of errors from pickle.py. Apart from this practical problem, I don't quite understand why anything but the final result of myfunc is being pickled at all.

Comment: Seems like `dill` doesn't work with Swig out of the box. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310053/how-to-make-my-swig-extension-module-work-with-pickle) that has a solution for making Swig objects pickleable. You might be able to leverage it.

Comment: I must admit, it even took me a moment to find out where the SwigPy object is coming from (I didn't define it myself). It turns out that one of the modules I am using in turn uses numerical libraries written in C. Digging through all there looks hard, but I will give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

`pathos` uses `dill`, and `dill` serializes classes differently than python's `pickle` module does.  `pickle` serializes classes by reference. `dill` (by default) serializes classes directly, and only optionally by reference.

```
>>> import dill
>>> 
>>> class Foo(object):
...   def __init__(self, x):
...     self.x = x
...   def bar(self, y):
...     return self.x + y * z
...   z = 1
... 
>>> f = Foo(2)
>>> 
>>> dill.dumps(f)  # the dill default, explicitly serialize a class
'\x80\x02cdill.dill\n_create_type\nq\x00(cdill.dill\n_load_type\nq\x01U\x08TypeTypeq\x02\x85q\x03Rq\x04U\x03Fooq\x05h\x01U\nObjectTypeq\x06\x85q\x07Rq\x08\x85q\t}q\n(U\r__slotnames__q\x0b]q\x0cU\n__module__q\rU\x08__main__q\x0eU\x03barq\x0fcdill.dill\n_create_function\nq\x10(cdill.dill\n_unmarshal\nq\x11Uyc\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00C\x00\x00\x00s\x0f\x00\x00\x00|\x00\x00j\x00\x00|\x01\x00t\x01\x00\x14\x17S(\x01\x00\x00\x00N(\x02\x00\x00\x00t\x01\x00\x00\x00xt\x01\x00\x00\x00z(\x02\x00\x00\x00t\x04\x00\x00\x00selft\x01\x00\x00\x00y(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00s\x07\x00\x00\x00<stdin>t\x03\x00\x00\x00bar\x04\x00\x00\x00s\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01q\x12\x85q\x13Rq\x14c__builtin__\n__main__\nh\x0fNN}q\x15tq\x16Rq\x17U\x01zq\x18K\x01U\x07__doc__q\x19NU\x08__init__q\x1ah\x10(h\x11Uuc\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00C\x00\x00\x00s\r\x00\x00\x00|\x01\x00|\x00\x00_\x00\x00d\x00\x00S(\x01\x00\x00\x00N(\x01\x00\x00\x00t\x01\x00\x00\x00x(\x02\x00\x00\x00t\x04\x00\x00\x00selfR\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00s\x07\x00\x00\x00<stdin>t\x08\x00\x00\x00__init__\x02\x00\x00\x00s\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01q\x1b\x85q\x1cRq\x1dc__builtin__\n__main__\nh\x1aNN}q\x1etq\x1fRq utq!Rq")\x81q#}q$U\x01xq%K\x02sb.'
>>> dill.dumps(f, byref=True)  # the pickle default, serialize by reference
'\x80\x02c__main__\nFoo\nq\x00)\x81q\x01}q\x02U\x01xq\x03K\x02sb.'
```

Not serializing by reference is much more flexible. However, in rare circumstances, working with references is better (as it appears to be the case when pickling something built on a `SwigPyObject`).

I have been meaning (for ~2 years) to expose the `byref` flag to the `dump` call inside of `pathos`, but have not done so yet.  It should be a fairly simple edit to do so.  I've just added a ticket to do so: https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos/issues/58.  While I'm at it, it should also be easy to open up replacement of the `dump` and `load` functions that `pathos` uses… that way you could use customized serializers (i.e. extend those that `dill` provides, or use some other serializer).

Comment: Great! Will check back on your ticket regularly, and of course try it once the edit is done.

Answer (score 1):

In multiprocessing function serialization is needed for interprocess communication. Pickle does a poor job for this purpose, install [dill](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill) via pip instead. Details (with a nice Star Trek example) can be found here:
http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2013/12/05/Parallelism-and-Serialization/

Comment: Thanks for the link. With the Star Trek example at least I understand why the methods have to be pickled. But in the above example I am already using pathos.multiprocessing and things still fail.

Comment: @barrios: I'm the `pathos` and `dill` author. The OP is correct. `pathos` uses `dill` out of the box.

Comment: sorry, didn,t know that.