# cPickle error while using pathos.multiprocessing?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, multiprocessing, pathos

I'm trying to use multiprocessing to speed up pandas excel reading. However when I use multiprocessing I'm getting the error 
**cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle : attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed**

when I try to run the following:
import dill
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessPool

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.files = glob.glob(\*)

    def read_file(self, filename):
        return pd.read_excel(filename)

    def file_data(self):
        pool = ProcessPool(9)
        file_list = [filename for filename in self.files]
        df_list = pool.map(A().read_file, file_list)
        combined_df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
```

Isn't pathos.multiprocessing designed to fix this issue? Am I overlooking something here?

Edit: 
Full error code traces to

```
File "c:\users\zky3sse\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pathos-0.2.0-py2.7.egg\
pathos\multiprocessing.py", line 136, in map
return _pool.map(star(f), zip(*args)) # chunksize
  File "C:\Users\ZKY3SSE\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 251, in map
return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Users\ZKY3SSE\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 567, in get
raise self._value
```

Comment: It looks like you are on windows, and if you didn't use freeze_support, you can get this cryptic error.  If you can post some test code that demonstrates your error that other people can run easily, you might get a more complete answer demonstrating working code.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that Pandas may be using Swig as a wrapper for C code. If this is the case, then dill may not work properly, and pathos would then switch to pickle. There are workarounds, as shown here: [How to make my SWIG extension module work with Pickle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310053/how-to-make-my-swig-extension-module-work-with-pickle)

Comment: Is there a way to check whether pandas is using swig?

Comment: I tried the link but that doesn't seem to have solved it