# Pathos can't pickle SwigPyObject created by GDAL module

Tags: python, oop, gdal, jpeg2000, pathos

I have a class which opens a large raster image using the GDAL module (https://pypi.org/project/GDAL/) and extracts small images from it at a number of locations, defined by a passed list of coordinate tuples. I want to process a large list of coordinates using Pathos, as in this simplified version of my code:

```
import gdal
import pathos.pools as pp

class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, image):
        self.image_object = gdal.Open(image)

    def get_small_image(self, coord, size=100):
        small_image = self.image_object.ReadAsArray(coord[0], coord[1], size, size)

        return small_image

    def run_multi(self, coords_in):
        pool = pp.ProcessPool(2)
        output = pool.map(self.get_small_image, coords_in)

        return output

image = r'C:\path\to\image.JP2'

class_obj = MyClass(image)
coords = [(200, 200), (400, 400), (600, 600), (800, 800)]
results = class_obj.run_multi(coords)

print(results)
```

Running this gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/lharris/PycharmProjects/road_condition_py3/error_recreate.py", line 26, in <module>
    results = class_obj.run_multi(coords)
  File "C:/Users/lharris/PycharmProjects/road_condition_py3/error_recreate.py", line 17, in run_multi
    output = pool.map(self.get_small_image, coords_in)
  File "C:\Users\lharris\PycharmProjects\road_condition_py3\venv\lib\site-packages\pathos\multiprocessing.py", line 137, in map
    return _pool.map(star(f), zip(*args)) # chunksize
  File "C:\Users\lharris\PycharmProjects\road_condition_py3\venv\lib\site-packages\multiprocess\pool.py", line 266, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Users\lharris\PycharmProjects\road_condition_py3\venv\lib\site-packages\multiprocess\pool.py", line 644, in get
    raise self._value
  File "C:\Users\lharris\PycharmProjects\road_condition_py3\venv\lib\site-packages\multiprocess\pool.py", line 424, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "C:\Users\lharris\PycharmProjects\road_condition_py3\venv\lib\site-packages\multiprocess\connection.py", line 209, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "C:\Users\lharris\PycharmProjects\road_condition_py3\venv\lib\site-packages\multiprocess\reduction.py", line 54, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\pickle.py", line 409, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python36\lib\pickle.py", line 751, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python36\lib\pickle.py", line 736, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python36\lib\pickle.py", line 736, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Users\lharris\PycharmProjects\road_condition_py3\venv\lib\site-packages\dill\_dill.py", line 1377, in save_function
    obj.__dict__), obj=obj)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\pickle.py", line 610, in save_reduce
    save(args)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python36\lib\pickle.py", line 751, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python36\lib\pickle.py", line 736, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Users\lharris\PycharmProjects\road_condition_py3\venv\lib\site-packages\dill\_dill.py", line 1120, in save_cell
    pickler.save_reduce(_create_cell, (f,), obj=obj)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\pickle.py", line 610, in save_reduce
    save(args)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python36\lib\pickle.py", line 736, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Users\lharris\PycharmProjects\road_condition_py3\venv\lib\site-packages\dill\_dill.py", line 1069, in save_instancemethod0
    pickler.save_reduce(MethodType, (obj.__func__, obj.__self__), obj=obj)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\pickle.py", line 610, in save_reduce
    save(args)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python36\lib\pickle.py", line 736, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\pickle.py", line 521, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\pickle.py", line 634, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Users\lharris\PycharmProjects\road_condition_py3\venv\lib\site-packages\dill\_dill.py", line 893, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\pickle.py", line 821, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "C:\Python36\lib\pickle.py", line 852, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\pickle.py", line 521, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\pickle.py", line 634, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Users\lharris\PycharmProjects\road_condition_py3\venv\lib\site-packages\dill\_dill.py", line 893, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\pickle.py", line 821, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "C:\Python36\lib\pickle.py", line 852, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\pickle.py", line 496, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
TypeError: can't pickle SwigPyObject objects
```

Looking through that, it does look as though Pathos is using Dill and Multiprocess correctly. So is there a way of dealing with SwigPyObjects in parallel, either using Pathos or otherwise?

Something similar was asked a few weeks ago, but didn't get any answers ([Python pathos error can't pickle SwigPyObject objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50874803/python-pathos-error-cant-pickle-swigpyobject-objects)), and I asked a related question when I was previously unable to use Pathos ([How can type 'SwigPyObject be registered using copy_reg.pickle in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51038892/how-can-type-swigpyobject-be-registered-using-copy-reg-pickle-in-python)).

I encountered this error using Python 3.6.5, in Windows 7, developing in PyCharm, using a virtual environment onto which any packages I need have been pip installed from .whl files downloaded from PyPi (I'm unable to use pip install normally on my network).

Any help anyone can give me would be great!

Answer (score 2):

Because `get_small_image` is a bound method each worker is needs a copy of `class_obj`. With multiprocessing this is done by passing pickled python objects. However because the object contains a member of class `SwigPyObject` `class_obj` isn't pickable and the whole thing fails.

The most straight forward fix is something like:

```py
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, image):
        self.image_object = None
        self.image = image

    def get_small_image(self, coord, size=100):
        if self.image_object is None:
            self.image_object = gdal.Open(self.image)

        small_image = self.image_object.ReadAsArray(coord[0], coord[1], size, size)

        return small_image

    def run_multi(self, coords_in):
        pool = pp.ProcessPool(2)
        output = pool.map(self.get_small_image, coords_in)

        return output
```

This lazy loading of the image causes the `SwigPyObject` to be created *after* the object has been pickled/unpickled by the child processes and thus avoiding the issue you are encountering.